# How would we limit the drop down for the Date's Timzone field?

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n, datetime

We are using the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module that allows for enabling of Timezone during node edit (node/edit). We noticed that the dropdown is really long and we were wondering if there was a way to shorten the list to just say ETC, PST, UTC, GMT, etc.

We tried all the configuration setting, but could not shorten the drop down.

Current scenario:

[image]

Desired scenario:

Timezone (as an example)
 - UTC
 - PST/PDT
 - MST/MDT
 - EST/EDT
 - GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date module's field elements are supplied by the Date API module. The timezone component is supplied by its process callback [`date_timezone_element_process()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api!date_api_elements.inc/function/date_timezone_element_process/7).

It triggers [`hook_date_timezone_process_alter()`](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!date!date.api.php/function/hook_date_timezone_process_alter/7.41) which can be evoked by a custom module to alter the options within `$element['timezone']['#options']`.

For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_date_timezone_process_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_date_timezone_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, &$context) {

  if (isset($element['timezone']['#options'])) {
    // @TODO: Supply an array filter function that filters
    // IANA TZ names that don't correspond to
    // UTC - PST/PDT - MST/MDT - EST/EDT - GMT

    // Example: Filter TZ's that are only in the Americas
    $element['timezone']['#options'] = array_filter($element['timezone']['#options'], function($key) {
      return strpos($key, 'America/') !== FALSE;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

  }
}
```

Comment: The main issue we are having is that the time zone dropdown list does not show any of the values that we need. There are no MST, EST, GMT, etc and we cannot find another option for this. Would this hook alter be able to help use to ensure that when the node is saved with that time zone (assuming we can limit it to what we want) that the correct time zone is displayed on the node view?

Comment: The hook exposes the data structures used to build the TZ form component and present it to the user. It doesn't have a say in validation (on form submission), or presentation (on node view). The best thing it can do is prevent invalid data from being an option.